# DotStar micro LED run at 3.3 V

Tags: lithium-ion, led-strip, rgb

I am designing a [Binary Coded Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) watch which uses DotStar micro LEDs for the watch face and an ATtiny1616 MCU.

I want the watch to run off a Li-ion battery, but I am stuck on this circuit since DotStars require 5 V to run according to the datasheet.

Can these LEDs be run at a lower voltage (3.5 V or lower)? I ask because I would like to avoid using a second battery cell in series, and add a regulator to get the correct voltage.

Comment: The datasheet for the SK9822 LEDs don't define a minimum voltage it works with, typical is 5V. Have you tried them at 3.3V? Also, increasing battery voltage and regulating it down to 5V is not the only option, there are other options as well, so why not ask a question about what you are trying to achieve, instead of asking how to implement it with the way you have already decided.

Comment: You could boost the single cell. Basically build your own usb power bank.

Comment: And lower than 3.3V and your going to start losing the green and blue brightness.

Comment: I haven't used these exact LEDs, but for regular WS2812 parts: They are designed to be used on strips that can have significant voltage drop in the wiring, so they have some allowance for that. Somewhere around 4.2 V the constant current driver stopped working so the brightness wasn't controlled anymore. The part will probably work at lower voltages, but uncontrolled brightness isn't acceptable to me, so I didn't investigate further. I suggest that you run some tests.

Comment: Would a boost converter work?

Comment: The idle power consumption of these LEDs is a problem for batteries.

Comment: You can use something like a https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX660.pdf which is a capacitive voltage doubler with efficiency as high as 98%. You can also achieve the same thing using PWM from a microcontroller with two diodes and two capacitors.